# Why does this SQL query result in an undefined index error?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand why I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in E:\xampp\htdocs\CVToolGismo\addCV.php on line 472

The part of the code that I get the error is this:

```
if($query = mysql_query("SELECT job_title,company,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,work_history FROM work WHERE username='$username' order by id asc limit 1") or die(mysql_error())){
                  if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                         $id = $row['id'];
                    }
                  }
                  else{
                      echo '<script>ErrorMessage()</script>';
                  }
              }
```

Comment: Because you’re not selecting a column named `id` in your statement …?

Comment: @EmmadKareem it is a compination of the id and the username

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. I'm sure it's a duplicate of *some* question, but not *that* one.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Please tell me why this should not be a dupe?! He wants to access an undefined index in an array, from my perspective this is an exact dupe

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it is not a duplicate question

Comment: @Rizier123: That question covers the general case of the index not existing. The issue in this question is that the asker has deliberately crafted their code (and specifically their SQL query) to invoke the error.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But don't you think with a little debugging and the use of google he would have spotted that? Also *I'm sure it's a duplicate of some question* If you know about a dupe which I'm not aware of, why do you answer a duplicate question?

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't have a `id` column.

Comment: if I place the id and make my select like this ... "SELECT job_title,company,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,work_history FROM work WHERE id>'$id' AND username='$username' order by id asc limit 1" ... I am still getting this error :/

Comment: That query still doesn't have a `id` column.

Comment: After the WHERE I have this id>'$id'

Comment: That's a criterion, not a column.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you haven't actually selected the id column. You must query the id column in the `SELECT` statement to use it.